# Duplicate jobs in SQS FiFo Laravel 8.0 queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

I am using a command in Laravel 8.0 to dispatch 1000+ jobs into an Amazon SQS FiFo queue. And I will process them using the command `php artisan queue:work` which goes fine by its own. But when I am spinning up multiple CLI sessions and start the queue workers, they all starting to pick up the exact same job every time.

I was also experiencing this problem when using Redis, but I was hoping to solve this problem by using SQS FiFo. Am I doing something wrong, or should I use an other service for this kind of purpose?

Comment: Your issue here is you're expecting PHP to have multiple threads: this is incorrect. PHP executes and exits, you cannot multi-thread the script. If you want multiple threads, use a different language. Furthermore, if you **really** want to run the script multiple times and hope they don't collide, then integrate some sort of Database and utilise its lock features.

Comment: Are you sure you're using an SQS FIFO queue and not a normal SQS queue? Laravel doesn't support SQS FIFO queues out of the box; did you install a package in order to support it? If so, which package?

Comment: @patricus I installed the package `shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue` to enable support for SQS FiFo.

@Jaquarh and @patricus: The weird part is, when I use Redis, SQS FiFo or beanstalkd locally, open 4 CLI sessions and run the workers non of the workers pick up the same job. But the moment I start adding servers to run workers they start picking up the same jobs.